# Soundfont with Timidity

Tags: sound, midi

Is there an easy intuitive (user-friendly) way to use a soundfont with timidity ?
I have seen some complicated how-to but it's not convenient at all for a end-user.

Answer (score 1):

I struggled with this recently; it turned out to be simple ...

Nautilus > file system/etc/timidity/timidity.cfg

Use gedit to look at the file; as it happened, lucky me, both soundfonts were in the folder! At the bottom of the config file, I commented out the freepats.cfg entry (simply put the # in front of the line) and select the fluid-soundfont (remove the #)
:-)

Of course, if you haven't the alternate soundfont, you'll have to find it. It is:

fluid3_gs.cfg

Now I have to figure out how to fix Totem ...

Answer (score 1):

The bare minimum that you need in your timidity.cfg config file:

> dir /home/usr/Downloads/soundfonts

Point out where the soundfont file is located

> bank 0

which instrument sounds we are going to provide for midi files that access bank 0 (hat tip to [this doc](https://sudoit.blogspot.com/2009/08/starting-with-timidity-and-soundfonts.html))

> 0 %font soundfont.sf2 0 0

- <midi_instrument> %font <soundfont.sf2> <soundfont_bank><soundfont_instrument>
- midi_instrument: the program change found in the midi file.
- %font: means this is a soundfont (patches don't require it), then .
- soundfont_bank: the bank as in your soundfont
- soundfont_instrument: the instrument number in your soundfont

In order to know the bank, presets and instruments provided in the Soundfont file, you'll need a SountFont Viewer such as Polyphone